# Express is not handling errors for function

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, module-export

I'm using a function for multiple times by calling from different routes. It's running but express/node.js not handling errors in the function.

Here's the example.

```
# routes.js
var app = express()
var { test } = require('../functions/test.js')(app)

router.get('/test', (req, res) => {
  console.log(test())
})
```

```
# test.js
function test() {
  return 'Hey'
}

module.exports = function(app){
  return { test }
}
```

If I call a function in `test()` which is not exists, It's not throwing errors and returns nothing inside `console.log(test())`

```
# test.js
function test() {
  heyHeyheyHey()
  return 'Hey'
}

module.exports = function(app){
  return { test }
}
```

Do I have to define this module in somewhere or something?

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: In the second example, there is not a declared heyHeyheyHey() function. when you call test() from route it has to throw error. But it's not throwing any error.

Comment: Could you provide more details? What is your codes expected output? What is it actually outputting? What are you trying to achieve with this code?

Comment: @TanerTunçer are you sure, the path to the test.js file is correct & you might have two test.js file at two different locations, & you're requiring the wrong one

Comment: you are not doing any error handling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran a quick demo and the error has been thrown. I'm sure you've figured it out but here is my snippet.
[image]

[image]